# Accessing property from a class of list

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio

I was trying to display the values that are inside of fieldValues. Which fieldValues hold "Information" and "Error". At first I did a simple `Console.Writeline(fieldValues)` but I soon learned that that was just really using `ToString()` implementation of List simply printing the name of the type which is not what I wanted to display. I then tried to create a foreach loop since the property `FieldLevel` is a list of type `<FieldValue>` which holds a property of string `value` which holds "Information" and "Error".

`model class:`

```
public class LevelField
{
   public string FieldName { get; set; }
   public List<FieldValue> FieldValue { get; set; }
}

public class FieldValue
{
   public string value { get; set; }
}
```

`in my other class:`

```
 var fieldName = "";
 List<FieldValue> fieldValues = new();

......

foreach (var y in x.BusinessProcessStep.LogDataSources)
{
    fieldName = y.LogDataSource.LogFieldsMapping.LevelField.FieldName;
    fieldValues = y.LogDataSource.LogFieldsMapping.LevelField.FieldValue;
}

foreach (var item in fieldValues.FirstOrDefault().value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

However, in the fieldValues foreach loop it only returned the letter "I" not information and error. **Is there a specific way to call the property value from List FieldValue?**

Comment: Why `FieldValue.value` is a string and not a class which has properties `Information` and `Error`? Why the letter `"I"` is returned? Is that the delimiter of both information? Then you have to show us where you generate it, probably there's the reason of this issue. If you want to output all `FieldValue` you could also use `String.Join`: `string result = string.Join("|", fieldValues.Select(fv => fv.value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, you need to iterate through all the `fieldValues` list and not only on the first item as you do.

Try this:

```
foreach (string item in fieldValues.Select(fv => fv.value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Or this:

```
foreach (FieldValue item in fieldValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.value);
}
```

Or with `System.Linq`:

```
fieldValues.ForEach(fv => Console.WriteLine(fv.value));
```

Comment: I see now it makes sense why it was returning what I needed it to display! Thank you for your help!! I got it to display now :)